# jQuery animate remaining divs after .fadeOut() and .remove()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fadeout

Ok, so I have a sequence of divs and, after removing one of them, I wanted the ones below to animate up, like a transition, instead of the normal behavior of just jumping up fast.

```
$('input#del').click(function() {
    var div = $('div:eq(1)', contentDiv);
    div.fadeOut(timeout, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

**Here's a fiddle** of what I got:

http://jsfiddle.net/US5Vr/

Thank you!

Comment: what about using slideUp.? http://jsfiddle.net/US5Vr/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gQ8UA/1/ - slideUp()

Comment: @ArunPJohny Hummm... although it's not perfect, it's better than the fadeOut option. I wonder if I could have both!?